# centering <p> without setting width

Tags: html, css

I have a error message to be displayed
i can center it using text-align center if there was no background. but now its clearly visible that it occupies the whole width of the container it being a `<p>`.

so i gave width and margin:0 auto;
but i cant give its class to every other error message because width changes.
so is there any way to center it without giving width.

here is what i currently have [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avi_sagi/67vmv/)

HTML:

```
<p class="error"><b>Error:</b> Dont select corners, select edges!</p>
```

CSS:

```
.error{
    padding:15px;
    border:1px solid #ebccd1;  
    border-radius:4px;  
    background-color: #f2dede;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family:consolas;
    font-size:17px;  
    color:#a94442;
    width:370px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:table` for the `p`:

```
.error {
  ...
  display:table;
}
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/67vmv/1/)

Comment: such simple answer which fixes everything, who would expect a table would work! :D

Comment: @DanielCheung in fact CSS table layout is fairly flexible. In many cases, only it can solve the problem (while the most modern layout is still not supported well by older versions of browser)

Answer (score 4):

Change the display of the `p` element to `inline-block` and then add `text-align:center` to the parent element to center it.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sr5Pq/)

```
.parent {
    text-align:center;
}
.error {
    padding:15px;
    border:1px solid #ebccd1;
    border-radius:4px;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    font-family:consolas;
    font-size:17px;
    color:#a94442;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could change the display of the `p` element to `table` as [King King points out](http://jsfiddle.net/7NRpU/).

It's worth noting that [this approach wouldn't work in IE7 though](http://caniuse.com/css-table).